# Is it possible to configure a router to work in AP mode but receive internet from another wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet

I would like to setup a router so that it receives the internet signal from another router wifi's and works in AP mode, so that my wifi devices can connect to it. NOT repeater mode, cause I want to be able to connect to any wifi signal to receive internet. Is it possible? I believe it would require 2 wifi radios, since one would be used to connect to the AP with Internet and the other would provide AP access. Maybe a special firmware could do that with just one radio?

Comment: There is no special firmware to do it with one radio, you need two radios (that does not mean two boxes, just one box with two radios built in, it is becoming more and more popular so they are not hard to find)

Comment: could you give me some brands/models?

Comment: I own a [WNDR3300](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/wirelessrouters/high-performance/wndr3300.aspx#) that does it, but just look at the product specs, it should say if it has two radios.

Comment: do you mean that dual band products could do it?

Comment: No, "Dual Band" is marketing speak, it may or many not mean two radios. In this case it does, but I would not rely on that term when choosing a router.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called a wifi repeater, how you implement it depends on your hardware, if you can install DD-WRT on it, you're most of the way there. [This](http://lifehacker.com/5563196/turn-your-old-router-into-a-range+boosting-wi+fi-repeater) is a nice article exaplining the concept using DD-WRT, but you can also find this function on normal AP firmware, though sometimes the machines which it can connect to are limited (usually to the same manufacturer).

Comment: That's normal wifi repeater mode. I already work with that. Problem is if the internet signal drops also the AP drops, doesn't show anymore to connect. It's only active/visible when the AP it is repeating is available.

Comment: You certainly didn't mention that requirement in your question :) You could also use WDS or bridge Mode, but again, if the internet connected node has issues, you won't be able to connect to the internet.

Comment: sorry, you are right, my mistake, already fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, that moves the goalposts a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need two antennas with separate radios. The Ruckus MetroFlex 2211 can do this. Your router probably not. You can use DD-WRT (as NickW suggested), and use it to receive a wifi-connection. Then the ethernet cable can connect to a second wifi-router which acts normally.

Comment: yeah I would like to have something that would do it in one piece. Probably this one you said is expensive. I believe it could be implemented in firmware with just one radio, since wireless repeating is similar to what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Some wifi radios can handle host and client operation at the same time. The problem with such a setup is a radio can only work on one frequency channel at a time, this poses a couple of problems.

1. Both the upstream and the downstream connections will be on the same channel and will therefore be sharing wireless bandwidth.
2. If the upstream connection changes channel the downstream connection must also change channel.

So two radios while not strictly essential are highly desirable.

Personally I would probablly grab a Raspberry Pi 3, use the onboard wireless for the host and grab a wifi dongle for the client. It's reasonablly economical and when things change the Pi can be reused for other things but then i'm comfortable setting up generic Linux systems as routers.